# apt-get not using http_proxy in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apt, 13.10, sudo, proxy, environment-variables

I just updated from Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.10

In 12.04, I used to set up my http_proxy variable in .bashrc and then use apt-get as follows

```
sudo -E apt-get update
```

The -E option in sudo used to make the user environment variables available to sudo and apt-get would pick up the http_proxy variable.

For some reason, this method is not working in 13.10. I am repeatedly getting `407 Proxy authentication Required`.

Does anybody know the reason why? How do I solve this?

**Note**:
I know that the other way to enable proxy for apt-get is to change settings in apt.conf. I don't want to do this as this will create a system wide setting. Also, when I am using the system at home (where there is no proxy), I will again have to go and change apt.conf.
In the above solution, I would just have to drop the "-E" option in sudo and apt-get will just attempt to directly connect to the internet.

Comment: The 407 error indicates apt-get is using the proxy but the username and password required are not provided or are invalid. Are you sure you added the proxy this way: export http_proxy='http://username:password@host:port/;? And if yes, are you sure you have escaped special characters like `@` and `:`, if you have them in your password?

Comment: Yes, I have an @ in my password and I have escaped it with %40. The same proxy is working in firefox. So, I don't think the problem is because of authentication. There is something going wrong when apt-get is getting the proxy variables

Comment: The better way of escaping characters is using a `\\`, though I am not sure what `%40` is. Try using `\\` before the `@` in your password.

Comment: If you want to test, try `wget`ing something and see if it works.

Comment: %40 is the HTML encoding for @. This used to work in 12.04. wget works with this too. Anyways, I tried esaping with \. Wierdly even wget does not work with this.

Comment: wget requires that you provide your proxy in `/etc/wgetrc` file. Did you do that?

Comment: No, wget works perfectly by reading the http_proxy variable, when @ is replaced by %40. When I replace it with \@, I get the following error `Resolving xyz@proxyhost (xyz@proxyhost)... failed: Name or service not known.` where xyz is the part of my password after @.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide your proxy with the authentication parameters in your `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file as `export http_proxy=http://username:password@host:password/`.

If you have special characters(non-alphanumeric characters) like `"`, `'`, `@`, `:` etc. in your password, you should use the HTML codes for the characters instead.

For example, if you password is `p@ssw0rd`, you should type the password as `p%40ssw0rd` in the `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file and then export these variables to the current session as `source /home/$USER/.bashrc`. (%40 is the HTML code for `@`.)

Comment: Yes, I have done that and I am able to use wget perfectly with it. The only problem is with apt-get, may be because it is being run with sudo. Sudo needs to pass on the environment variables to apt-get and this is what -E was doing. But now it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What do you get when you do a `sudo -E echo $http_proxy`?

Comment: When I do `sudo -E echo $http_proxy`, I get the proper value of the proxy that I had assigned. The weird part is that even `sudo echo $http_proxy` (without -E) produces the same result. My understanding is that it shouldn't.

Comment: Sincerely, no idea what's happening :(

Comment: For some weird reason there was a wrong acquire proxy setting in my apt.conf. This was causing all the problems. Now, apt is working as expected. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I want to accept your answer, but can you once make sure if escaping with \ is the right thing to do. Because doing so made wget to throw errors while replacing @ with %40 worked as expected

Comment: It seems like using HTML codes is the best way here, please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901839/how-to-escape-the-symbol-in-bash I'll wait for answers to this question, meanwhile have modified my answer.